# NullPointerException on mockito spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, jdbctemplate

i have a DAO class that I am trying to write test cases

Here is modified reproducible code

the DAO class I am trying to test

```
@Component
public class SomeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


    public boolean dataInTable(String id) {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
                "FROM table1" +
                "WHERE id =:id";



        MapSqlParameterSource sqlParms = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        sqlParms.addValue("id", id

        try {
            int count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, sqlParms, Integer.class);
            return (count > 0) ? true : false;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error checking existence of id : " + id);
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

When i run the test, it throws an NullPointer on

```
int count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, sqlParms, Integer.class);
```

so i believe mockito is not returning a value on when, thenReturn

i searched around stack overflow and it looks like what i have should work, but I am getting NullPointerException.

I have also tried using the same value for sql string and a mapObject as the dao class instead of anyString() and anyMap()

but did not work either

Test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeDAOTest {

    @InjectMocks
    SomeDAO someDao

    @Mock
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void TestdataInTable(){

        //
        when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), anyMap(),eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(1);
        assertEquals( true,someDao.dataInTable("123456"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
@Test
  public void TestdataInTable() {

    Mockito.when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class), Mockito.eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(1);
    assertEquals(true, someDao.dataInTable("123456"));
  }
```

1. The second parameter in queryForObject() is of type SqlParameterSource, which is not directly a map. So it should be, Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class).

The current version of your code displays warning in console, which is the best way to debug the issue.

```
[MockitoHint] TestDao.TestdataInTable (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at TestDao.TestdataInTable(TestDao.java:33)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at SomeDao.dataInTable(SomeDao.java:26)
```

Comment: On top of this answer: you don't need both `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` and `MockitoJUnitRunner` - keep only one of them. Also: `SqlParameterSource` is not a map at all. There are simply 2 overloaded versions of this method, and the wrong overload was mocked

Comment: This worked!. But I cannot vote or accept the answer since I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as it may help someone:

I had a similar issue but the reason was very different.
I was getting null pointer exception not just on `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` which was annotated with `@Mock` but also on `@InjectMocks`.

It so turn out that I was using Junit 5. The above solution will work with Junit 4. To make Mockito use Junit 5, an additional annotation is required. Also make sure you remove `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` as this will cause failure. Instead use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class`.

Here is an example:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) 
public class SomeDAOTest {

@InjectMocks
SomeDAO someDao

@Mock
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
```